# Image upload: Node Multer 'LIMIT_UNEXPECTED_FILE' error

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I'm trying to use multer to process a profile photp upload on the frontend to the backend but keep getting this error:

```
{ [Error: Unexpected field]
code: 'LIMIT_UNEXPECTED_FILE',
field: 'file',
storageErrors: [] }
```

Below is my code:

register.ejs:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" type="file" name="image" id="image">
</div>
```

ajax.js:

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = new FormData(this);
        // var img = cropper.getCroppedCanvas().toDataURL();
        // formData.append('img',img);
            $.ajax({
                url: '/register',
                type: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function () {
                    console.log('Upload success');
                    },
                error: function () {
                    console.log('Upload error');
            }
        });
    });
```

app.js:

```
var multer      = require('multer');
var cloudinary  = require('cloudinary');
...
// MULTER
var storage =   multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, "./public/uploads");
  },
  filename: function(req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, Date.now() + file.originalname);
  }
});

var upload = multer({ storage : storage}).single("image");

app.post("/register", function(req, res) {
  upload(req, res, function(err){
      if(err) {
           console.log(err);
           return res.send("Error uploading file.");
      }

     res.send("Upload success");
 });
});
```

I also get an undefined object when I try to get req.body.img or req.file. Maybe the formdata is not populated properly? Can anyone shed some light for me?

Comment: find a solution for this error? I am getting the same.

Answer (score 1):

It says on `multer` [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) that you should pass `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute to your `<form>` element. I'm not really familiar with `ajax`, but I think you may have to set `contentType:` in `ajax.js` to `"multipart/form-data"`.

I also had a similar error, but it was caused by non-matching text-field keys.

Answer (score 0):

I have also face the same issue, instead of using

> var upload = multer({ storage : storage}).single('image');

use the fields() method which allow to handle multiple files at once

> app.use(multer({ storage : storage}).fields([{name:'image',maxCount:1}]));

file data store in req.files ,
then you can simply handle the files

that error occur when you try to handle multiple form data object in single multer middleware,

you can use the `storage` option to store different files in different locations.

further more can go thought official doc

Answer (score 0):

When you call the multer function, maybe you forget to change the single field name. For example:

```
multer({ ... }).single("some_field_name");
```

Maybe `some_field_name` should be `other_field_name`. `some_field_name` and `other_field_name` are field names.